# Cannot use a python package installed using conda although the package exists (I specifically want a certain version)

Tags: python, import, pip, conda, folium

I have trouble (`ImportError: No module named folium`) importing folium 0.2.0 development version (I want this version). I installed the package via `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos folium` as this conda page mentions (https://anaconda.org/IOOS/folium). I indeed have the package on my mac (OSX El Captain) when I conda list (`folium 0.2.0 py27_3 ioos`). Why am I not able to use this package in Ipython (error on `import folium`)? Could someone help?

Some more info:

> which python

```
us/anaconda/bin/python
```

> which conda

```
/anaconda/bin/conda
```

Comment: from my short investigation, `anaconda` seems to be set up to use it's own prefix instead of installing packages to the standard location like `pip` does.

Comment: does this help you at all? http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Comment: Do you think you have to login first? I saw this message at https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos.   If you want to download secure private packages you must login first with: `anaconda login`

Answer (score 0):

try with pip:

```
pip install folium
```

but with pip you will get only folium 0.1.6

Comment: Thanks but yeah I know I can do that but I want 0.2.0 version.. Do you know how to figure this out?